# Using 120v GFCI outlet for 240v AC Source

Tags: lighting

Most GFCI (Ground Fault Circuit Interrupter) outlets are being sold for 120v only. Can it also work for 240v source? Anyone among you has 240v source and yet successfully used any 120v GFCI?

Note in principle a GFCI detects only difference in current. A 240v outlet would have smaller current.. so can we say all 120v GFCI outlets can work for 240v source?

Does the power source of the GFCI circuit uses switching adapter technology or fixed voltage step down transformer?

Comment: Why don't you simply use a 240V (two pole) GFCI breaker?

Comment: For a life safety device such as this, I wouldn't play games. Look for a device designed to work with your country's electric wiring system. A quick search on Amazon finds plenty of 2-pole GFCI designed for **USA** 240V == 2 pole. But if you are in Europe or other areas using 240V in a different way then those devices will likely NOT be what you want - or can use according to your local electrical code. And using a 120V GFCI device is not necessarily going to give you the proper level of protection - or necessarily function at all. Check with a **local** electrician or supply house.

Comment: Yes. My country ac system is compatible with the USA since they initially created our power system, however we only use 240V and never the 120V so we don't use neutral. Can these amazon 240v (two pole) GFCI breaker work without neutral connected?  I prefer GFCI outlets. But are GFCI breakers more advantageous? Or are GFCI outlets more sensitive?

Comment: @Samzun What country are you in?

Comment: Philippines. We used similar ac system as USA but only using the line to line of 240v. We never use line to neutral because we never have gadgets made for 120v. Does the European RCD take split phase of 240v or pure 240v hot to neutral? My loads have no neutral.. only line to line of 240volts. But most important.. does the European RCD have automatic self test (say every 1 minute) to check if the circuit is working or don't they follow the 2015 UL revision?

Comment: Also this is to confirm. This model Siemens QF240A has the GFCI working for both 120v and 240v or only for 240v? https://www.superbreakers.net/2-pole-circuit-breakers/siemens-qf260a-60-amp  click description

Answer (score 1):

### You want to use Euro-style RCD equipment for this

The Filipino power system can be treated as a split-phase, no-neutral (hot-hot) system using TT earthing (Terra-Terra, where the source transformer is connected to an earth electrode and local metal parts are connected to a different earth electrode, but there is no conductor connecting the two earth electrodes).  As a result of this, North American distribution equipment is only marginally suitable, as much of it assumes that an earthed neutral is distributed.

Instead, I would use two-pole (1P+N) Euro-style circuit breakers and RCDs (RCBOs, preferably, even, so that local socket-outlets can be used) -- however, instead of a single RCCB or RCBO incomer for the entire system, I would use a regular CB for the incomer and RCBOs with 10mA or 30mA residual (differential) trips for the individual circuits.  If you really want to use socket-outlet style equipment, SRCDs can be obtained and used with 10mA trips, but they have the disadvantage that they may not come in a suitable socket style for your local plugs.

(Furthermore, this is forward compatible to what the power utility wants to do over there, which is get you converted over to the IEC/Eurostyle system, full stop.)

Comment: Problem with getting European RCDs is that these RCDs don't have the sophisticated automatic self-test circuits that US products have. see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/402520/automatic-self-test-circuit-in-gfci-outlet/402522?noredirect=1#comment990273_402522 If I don't need automatic self-test. I could easily acquire local 240v GFCI (which doesn't have the feature). I need the feature because after installation. I don't want to constantly test it each month. The GFCI with automatic self test would just buzzer you after 15 years when the sensing circuit is destroyed by surge.

Comment: @Samzun -- aah.  if it makes you feel better -- most USians are pretty bad about testing their GFCIs :P

Comment: Our locally produced 240v has this written "250V 209A 6mA Sensitivity Rating *UL Safety Level for women and children". Those 2-pole gfci breakers at amazon don't have the sensitivity rating stated.. any ideas what is the typical value? https://www.amazon.com/Siemens-MP230GFA-Murray-Circuit-Breaker/dp/B01N32XPMU/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1540274898&sr=8-6&keywords=2+pole+gfci+breaker+30+amp  I need a 240v GFCI breaker with 6mA sensitivity and full automatic self-testing feature.

Comment: Hi, ThreePhaseEel.. Please share what models are the two Siemens Panels that are not compatible as mentioned by Harper in the thread https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/150196/mixing-north-american-panels-and-breakers/150211#150211  I'm waiting before I order a PL series http://pdf.lowes.com/useandcareguides/040892635836_use.pdf to use with my 6 Siemens QF230A 2-pole GFCI breakers... Thank you.

Comment: Siemens PL, ES, and EQIII LCs (as well as Murray) all use precisely the same breaker/busbar contact design (and are all *labeled* for use with Siemens QP and Murray MP breakers, at least on current production units)

Comment: So which Siemens panels have different design or not compatible as Harper noted in the other thread (he said "Siemens makes at least 2 panel types which are incompatible with each other.")? Also my Siemens QF260A 2-pole GFCI has the spring clip detail in the middle (the one on the right is a GE).  https://imageshack.com/a/img923/5629/P41jSN.jpg  For normal Siemens breakers without GFCI, are the spring clips similar? I'm asking because it seems the Siemens GFCI breaker needs very thick bus bar to have full metal contacts.

Comment: Btw.. you were the one who suggested me to buy 2-pole breaker to get the 240v and I have spent 3 weeks doing just that :) Thanks for the tip. Now I'm making sure the enclosure I'll order at amazon will be perfect. Shipping is 150% the cost of the unit so it's only a 1 time shot.Please see the spring clips of the Siemens QF260A 2-pole closed up here https://imageshack.com/a/img923/2578/AHMBad.jpg  Is it the same as other normal siemens breakers (without GFCI) spring clips.. note it's so slant because it needs very thick bus bar. but normal Siemens panels don't seem to have very thick bus bar..

Comment: ThreePhaseEel, kindly comment on this https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/150771/siemens-breakers-dont-fit-siemens-panel-completely-why  about Siemens breaker not fitting properly in Siemens listed enclosure... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No.  A 120V GFCI is not insulated for 240V.   Its internal electronics are not made to run 240V.

Worse still, you would be putting 240V on two NEMA 5 sockets, which is asking for a house fire when someone *perfectly reasonably* plugs in a 120V load, expecting 120V since it is NEMA 5.  You can at least avoid this problem by using a deadfront (socketless) GFCI.

Why not just use European GFCIs (the term for them is RCDs)? **They are made for 240V**.

Or you could use American 240V GFCIs, they do not require neutral (just don't hook it up).

Comment: but for American 240v GFCI, you need to hook up neutral because it's internal circuitry is using 120v (by tapping hot to neutral)… https://www.amazon.com/Siemens-MP230GFA-Murray-Circuit-Breaker/dp/B01N32XPMU/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1540274898&sr=8-6&keywords=2+pole+gfci+breaker+30+amp  i'll research about European RCDs.. I wonder they accept 120v line to line (producing 240v like in US) or they need 240v hot and neutral input.. what do you think?

Comment: European RCDs have significantly different trip currents. Some (but not all) do not care about where the supply is ground-referenced. I am not sure on whether 50 vs 60Hz would be an issue. If your load has a neutral, European ones will not work for you.

Comment: @Samzun where are you seeing that this breaker needs neutral?  I don't see that.

Comment: according to this poster jeroen3 "It looks like it can switch 240V, but need the tail connected to neutral for 120V power supply."  It's reasonable that the GFCI circuit needs 120v power supply instead of 240v, isn't it? see this chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84813/discussion-between-jeroen3-and-samzun

Comment: @Harper -- many 2-pole GFCI designs need 120V for the electronics package. (It's *possible* to build a natively 240V GFCI, but that'd require a different circuit board than the 1-pole version, which is why manufacturers of North American breakers don't do it that way)

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere GFCI's don't use ground and therefore don't know where the ground reference is.  It's true most Euro GFCIs are 30ma (their purpose is wiring protection not life safety) but they surely make life safety units at or around  the 8ma figure.

Comment: @Harper Per NZ regulations, 30mA RCDs are considered to provide 'personal protection'. 10mA units are required for certain situations (primary schools and medical treatment areas) where people may be at elevated risk. Some RCBOs (RCDs with overcurrent protection) have a functional earth conductor to power the electronics in the event of a lost neutral. Some also only open one pole (but I think these aren't allowed here), so cannot be used with two active conductors.

Comment: @Harper -- 30mA RCDs are designed to protect against fibrillation and wiring hazards, but not "let-go" muscle contraction hazards (falls, Electric Shock Drowning).  As Someone said, IEC-based systems have 10mA RCDs as an equivalent to our Class A (5-8mA) GFCI protection (the reason for the 2x trip point should be obvious :).  The [BEAMA handbook on RCDs](http://www.beama.org.uk/asset/7062C3E9-70C0-4196-83FE5C315D958BC3/) can be referred to for more info.

Comment: So all 2-pole gfci breakers in amazon with Class A rating has really 5 to 8mA interrupting current? Class A doesn't refer to the breaker function itself? Please confirm before I order one there. It's something I couldn't return anymore because it would be shipped half a world away and returning it would incur huge shipping costs. Thanks guys (is the word "thank" not allowed in PSE.. it's weird one can't mention it)

Comment: I plan to buy this item.. the Siemens QF260A.. click description at https://www.superbreakers.net/2-pole-circuit-breakers/siemens-qf260a-60-amp   it states: "It features an interrupt rating of 10kA at 240V".. what is interrupt rating? how does it different to trip sensitivity of 5mA? I guess this is the best model that has automatic self test feature that you can install and forget.. any comment about it?

Comment: Do you have a panel it will fit in?  Which would be, specifically, a Siemens panel. Don't buy it unless you do.  If you have some other manufacturer's panel, buy their breakers.  North American style breakers do not interchange among panels.  They seem to, and many will snap in, but they will burn the bus bars if you try.   10kA is the amount of current the breaker can interrupt, i.e. If you have a dead short and it's pulling thousands of amps.  It's expressed in SI units.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel on the need for 120V to power the GFCI's guts, here's an idea: a North American panel in the Phillippines has a neutral bus that is completely unused. Use it.  Install a 5 VA (that should be enough) 240V center-tap autotransformer in there, tie the center tap to the neutral bar.  Then land all the GFCI pig's tails on the neutral bar.

Comment: @Harper -- that actually *could* work OK (it'd be similar to the use of a "zigzag" grounding transformer in a 3ph system)

Comment: @Harper, any illustration? If a separate 5V autotransformer is used, can it trick the Siemens unit into seeing the neutral that is not there? You mean just feeding the autotransformer zero volt neutral to the 2-pole gfci breaker neutral without connecting anything else in the autotransfomer?  Also my local 240v gfci tripped a while ago, must be leakage current. If I used the 2-pole 60A Siemens QF260A gfci breaker, would the 60A breaker itself trip or separate tripping mechanism inside it?

Comment: Btw.. about what panel I have to pair with the Siemens.. I will not use any extra panel. I'll just take the wire from an existing 2 pole breaker and connect it to the Siemens Gfci which will just stay at the wooden cabinet bottom.

Comment: 5 ***VA*** not V, big difference.  The transformer wouldn't trick the Unit into working without neutral. It would create an actual though unbonded neutral for it to use.  Of course at 5 VA it would fry instantly if you plugged in any substantial 120V load, it wouldn't even charge a cell phone... but it would suffice for powering GFCIs needing 120V for internal circuitry. US breakers are made for use in specific panels, not loose. You will not be happy. Use a Euro breaker.

Comment: My panel doesn't even have a neutral bar. See pictures (and my plan) at https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/149346/single-plug-in-breaker-connector-or-interface Important: please tell me where shall I connect the 220v and 0v secondary outputs of the autotransformer. Is it to the GFCI breaker or the ac supply? You only share about the centertap (110v) of the autotransformer connecting to the neutral of the Siemens GFCI breaker. Maybe you can reply at the new thread above. I can ask about the tapping the neutral part there so this comments won't be long.

Comment: Harper. Maybe you can answer it on the electrical forum where to connect one of the red leads of the 240V center-tap. To the house outlet or the GFCI input. See: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/404381/connecting-a-pseudo-neutral-to-pig-tail-of-gfci