# Single Plug-In Breaker Connector or Interface

Tags: protection

This is my panel at home. I live in the Philippines. We only use 240V. We never get inspection. I need to add a special state of the art Siemens Gfci 2-pole breaker with automatic self-test feature that I couldn't find in 240v outlet version. Not even the RCDs in any European country has the UL advanced auto self-test feature.

[image: 1]

I will just put the following Siemens QF260A GFCI 2-pole breaker at the bottom of the above panel board.

[image: 2]

Can anyone share how I can connect the plug in portion.. like maybe is there a standalone connector (without needing panel) that I can use so I can connect it to the wire that will be tapped to one of the existing breakers output in the panel (imagine 2 breakers in series). Or what is the smallest single breaker panel I can use that is compatible with the breaker. Is the plug in portion of the Siemens standard?

For European users. You can adapt this too to your country 230v system and take advantage of the very advanced self-test feature available only in US GFCI where you no longer have to worry the sensing part of the circuit would suddenly cease to function. When it does after say 16 years, the breaker will just cease to function and lock itself out.

Comment: If your goal is to increase the safety of your electrical service by adding a GFCI, then adding it on by some sort of haphazard, "life-hack" way is going to provide exactly the opposite of that - you're going to decrease the safety of your electrical service. Don't attempt to "patch this in" or wire it without an enclosure or "tap in one of the existing breakers". That's simply asking for trouble. If you're going to the expense of adding this for safety, then add safety in _every_ step of the process.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your panel is full if this is for a new circuit you will need to install some tandem or double stuff breakers to make room or add a sub panel to provide more slots. If this is to add safety for an existing circuit or group (I think this is your goal) pull the old breaker and install this new breaker. What is the smallest size panel ? That would be a 60 amp since this breaker is 60, however I would probably go with a 100 amp panel with a few more extra slots and use this breaker to feed the sub panel then everything in the new sub panel would be protected by this breaker.

Comment: Do you know what panel the Siemens QF240A is compatible to?  There doesn't seem to be a panel type written it its spec sheet  see: https://www.downloads.siemens.com/download-center/Download.aspx?pos=download&fct=getasset&id1=BTLV_47316    Since it is the best GFCI breaker in the planet. I think I'll order 2 pcs and worry about the enclosure later.. because there is just no other choice.