# Siemens Spring Clip and Bus Bar not compatible!

Tags: electrical

According to a Siemens customer service. He checked his stock too and it's like that, and it was supposed to be normal. Is it really normal to have the spring clip and bus bar stab only having electrical contacts at the bottom? He wrote:
"I have checked older GFCI 20amp 2 pole breaker that has same structure that you show & fits the same as your photos indicate. The surface contact of the breaker contacts to the load center stabs seems to be sufficient & has not changed and there have been no reports of failures."

In 1998 and 2010. Siemens QP were recalled due to one reported failure. So do they have to expect smoke and fire before it is considered as one report? Does anyone who have accessed to more knowledgeable Siemens engineers please ask them about this. Harper? Thanks.

[image: 1]

This is a more scientific test. I used a feeler gauge blade and inserted the thinnest (size 0.0015") in between the bus bar and spring clip:

[image: 2]

You can see only the contacts at the bottom of the spring clips and bus bar are connected. This is the same in all sides. Do you still agree that there is no problem? This can cause arcing, heat, burning, and fire. I think Siemens made a mistake. Their regular QP breakers fit perfectly (You can't insert any blade in any part).

How do I take this to the attention of Siemens? Their customers service said the breaker is a listed as compatible with the enclosure based on the literature but actual examination didn't support it.

Comment: Can you make measurements with calipers or a mm ruler on the spacing of the two sides of the breakers? Is the problem with the GFCI breaker that the spacing is wrong or is it that the gaps in the contacts for electrical contact are too large? Why do the GFCI breakers have the narrow slots on the face?

Comment: It's narrow at bottom because when you insert it.. it gets wider. But the problem is the bus bar is bit thinner by maybe 1mm so when you insert it all the way. It still doesn't make full contact with the top sides. see picture.. https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/1024x768q90/921/9r36c6.jpg so what happens is there is gap at top to mid where you can insert 2 sheets of paper... like this illustration. https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/640x480q90/922/5ja03X.jpg   maybe logic of Siemens is that there is enough area below for full electrical contact?? What do you guys think? All my 6 breakers same

Comment: For the regular Siemens QP breaker, notice the spring clips are narrower and perfect fit to the Siemens PL Load center... https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/1024x768q90/924/5MwhrQ.jpg  The Siemens GFCI 2-pole breakers in the earlier image have wider spring clips spacing. If anyone can talk with Siemens Technical, kindly ask why.

Comment: Paging @ThreePhaseEel ...

Comment: In this picture..  https://imageshack.com/a/img923/3739/8T1i1g.jpg  you can see all sides of the spring clips of the Siemens GFCI breaker can be inserted with paper (the right breaker is a regular Siemens QP breaker where you can't insert any paper in between the contacts). In the GFCI breaker, the contacts are at least half of the spring clips only.. but then if you see this picture of comparison between Siemens GFCI and GE breaker, http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img921/5959/1jAoAA.jpg   you can see the GE breaker only has small contact area equal to half the Siemens GFCI.. so it may work?

Comment: See updated post above of the actual area covered (half or more of contacts). Just teach me how to compute contact area and amperage flow so I can decide whether to continue using them or not. Thanks.

Comment: There are differences among Siemens breakers, but they are not that subtle.  They are things like "some bolt down, others clip in".  Weird.  I wonder if somehow you got a counterfeit breaker.  I would ask Siemens that...

Comment: Please do, kindly talk to Siemens breaker designers and concerned department.. all my 2pcs of GFCI from amazon and 4pcs from GFI Warehouse are similar , there is obviously contacts at the bottom only of the breakers spring clips with the bus bar.. one can easily insert gauge feeler after the breaker was installed fully. I'm not good in speaking English, the Siemens people may not understand my English if I talk to them.. hehe... thanks Harper..

Answer (score 4):

@samzun - very frustrating, it seems like you're doing your homework and still you have this problem.  It's very good that you caught it though.

I can only see three possibilities:

1. Someone at Siemens made a mistake confirming compatibility of this
   breaker.  I do not believe this to be the case, but Siemen's web
   site and literature are not really helpful.  If this is the case,
   I'd expect Siemens to provide the correct breaker.
2. The breaker is
   defective.  (Since other breakers fit, I doubt the panel bus is
   defective.)  Again I'd expect a warranty replacement either from the
   retailer or the manufacturer.
3. The breaker is a counterfeit.  You
   might get a refund from the retailer, but I'd bring it to Siemens
   attention.  Siemens and other manufacturers are very interested in
   stopping counterfeiters.  See this document from Siemens: [Counterfeit 
   Circuit Breakers: A Growing Threat](https://w3.usa.siemens.com/us/internet-dms/btlv/Residential/Residential/docs_Circuit%20Breakers/SIE_Counterfeit_BR.pdf)

If I can make a suggestion, in this and other questions, you are struggling quite a bit working with your panel bus.  It might make more sense to use DIN rail mountable breakers which are commonly used in Europe.  There's no bus with this system.  This seems to me a much easier way to retrofit GFCI protection with your panel.  For example look at the Eaton QPGF2030 or QPHGF2030 breakers.

Comment: Breaker is not defective nor counterfeit. I think Siemens may make it that way, the logic being there is still large electrical contact at half middle to bottom. See above comment to Jim Stewart, the Bus bar is thinner by maybe 1mm.. because if it's thicker.. then it can make full contact.. see pictures.. https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/1024x768q90/921/9r36c6.jpg and https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/640x480q90/922/5ja03X.jpg  In my country, GE breaker has very tiny electrical contact, so I guess even if one third make contact, it is as good as full and won't create arcing, heating etc.?

Comment: @Samzun - I just don't think it's worth the risk, the reduced contact area but more importantly the looseness is too risky.

Comment: looseness is not problem, it holds ok.. look at these 3 comparison picture between the Siemens GFCI, Siemens regular QP breaker and GE (General Electrical) 60A. https://imageshack.com/a/img921/5959/1jAoAA.jpg  Look at the spring clips of the GE, it's much smaller, almost 1/3 that of the Siemens GFCI. My country all use GE because of the small contact area that is compatible with any locally made panel. Therefore if GE can make their 60A use small contact area, that means it's accepted, hence maybe Siemens think even if the Seimens GFCI breaker has 1/3 contact area, it still works. What u think

Comment: It's just outside my comfort zone to make a guess based on your description, what if I guess wrong??

Comment: In the panel actual list of compatible breakers.. the QPF is listed.. see the blue arrow in https://imageshack.com/a/img921/7649/vRblMW.jpg  Also I wonder if the Siemens GFCI are only intended for use in the spa enclosure.. see  https://imageshack.com/a/img924/8481/BWPEjh.jpg    do you think it's bus bar is bigger? I can't compare between it based on picture and the my actual. And I don't want to spend another $100 just to buy the spa enclosure and check the bus bar size. Does it make sense Siemens GFCI are not intended to use for any normal home panel but only for spa?

Comment: Do you know what material is even thinner than paper? I want to see to what extend is there spacing even down the bottom of the contact. With paper, only half has spacing...

Comment: with thinner candy wrapper, the gap is even wider such that only the bottom is in contact.. https://imageshack.com/a/img922/3276/qJ0hDL.jpg  i'm hoping the other side has bigger contact area.. I wonder what is the email of Siemens Panel Design team

Comment: @samzun - if it says QPF is compatible in the panel's instructions, and the manufacturer verified the specific combination by part number, I don't know what more you could do to confirm compatibility, I don't see them designating a breaker QPF that doesn't work with QPF compatible bus...

Comment: Although it's written Type QPF here see pic https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/800x600q90/922/ze6v0N.jpg the string clips are not really type QP.. also do you know where to find the listed enclosures in "Use only on Listed Enclosures in the label"? There is only one in the Siemens enclosure I have now.. not the other way around (or the breaker list of compatible enclosure).. see label at https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/800x600q90/924/8j0TS0.jpg  Also It's assembled in the Philippines. I can't find the factory. Anyone know where it is? I wonder if I can talk to the assembly head.

Comment: See updated post above with more scientific test that shows only the bottom of the contacts are connected. I think it's not acceptable even if Siemens would still state they are compatible. It can cause arcing, burning, and fire with 60 ampere current. Harper said few contact points was only good for 2A.